# use slice in for loop to build a list

Tags: python, list, slice

I would like to build up a list using a for loop and am trying to use a slice notation. My desired output would be a list with the structure:

```
known_result[i] = (record.query_id, (align.title, align.title,align.title....))
```

However I am having trouble getting the slice operator to work:

```
knowns = "output.xml" 
i=0
for record in NCBIXML.parse(open(knowns)): 
    known_results[i] = record.query_id     
    known_results[i][1] = (align.title for align in record.alignment)     
    i+=1
```

which results in:

```
list assignment index out of range.
```

I am iterating through a series of sequences using BioPython's NCBIXML module but the problem is adding to the list. Does anyone have an idea on how to build up the desired list either by changing the use of the slice or through another method?

thanks zach cp

(crossposted at [Biostar])[1](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/15804/parse-ncbixml-output-into-a-python-list-of-hits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a value to a `list` at an index that doesn't exist. The way to add an element (at the end of the list, which is the common use case) is to use the `.append` method of the list.

In your case, the lines

```
known_results[i] = record.query_id     
known_results[i][1] = (align.title for align in record.alignment)
```

Should probably be changed to

```
element=(record.query_id, tuple(align.title for align in record.alignment))
known_results.append(element)
```

Warning: The code above is untested, so might contain bugs. But the idea behind it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
for record in NCBIXML.parse(open(knowns)): 
    known_results[i] = (record.query_id, None)     
    known_results[i][1] = (align.title for align in record.alignment)     
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right you want to assign every `record.query_id` one or more matching `align.title`. So i guess your query_ids are unique and those unique ids are related to some titles. If so, i would suggest a dictionary instead of a list.

A dictionary consists of a key (e.g. record.quer_id) and value(s) (e.g. a list of align.title)

```
catalog = {}

for record in NCBIXML.parse(open(knowns)):
   catalog[record.query_id] = [align.title for align in record.alignment]
```

To access this catalog you could either iterate through:

```
for query_id in catalog:
   print catalog[query_id]  # returns the title-list for the actual key
```

or you could access them directly if you know what your looking for.

```
query_id = XYZ_Whatever
print catalog[query_id]
```

Comment: nice method. I think that may be useful. The next step is to iteratively compare/score the contents of the two lists/dictionaries so whether it is a list or a dictionary is not too important. Are there performance gains to using a dictionary?

Comment: It depends. If you are doing for loops over all keys, then probably not. If you are can filter some keys, then probably yes. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.